# How to configure WCF Azure cloud service so that it can be updated without taking it offline?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, azure

I have an Azure Cloud Service with 1 web role. My web role has 2 WCF service project inside. My problem is that each service is dedicated to 1 client, but when updating, both services are taken offline while it re-uploads and updates the entire cloud service.

Should I be having these clients services as a separate Azure cloud service, or should I possibly have each one in its own web role?

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to avoid web services go offline, you should work with more than one role, then each role will receive the update at a time, avoiding offline time.

Comment: Thiago, thank you for your response. Would this be a viable solution in terms of resource usage and efficiency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Cloud Services, Virtual Machines and Virtual Network
>
> For Cloud Services, we guarantee that when you deploy two or more role
>   instances in different fault and upgrade domains, your Internet facing
>   roles will have external connectivity at least 99.95% of the time. For
>   all Internet facing Virtual Machines that have two or more instances
>   deployed in the same Availability Set, we guarantee you will have
>   external connectivity at least 99.95% of the time. For Virtual
>   Network, we guarantee a 99.9% Virtual Network Gateway availability.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/